# Растет количество потоков

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, таймер, rss

Помогите разобраться.
Делаю парсер RSS лент на Retrofit.
Запускаю чтение лент через Timer. Растет количество потоков. Почему?

Тестовый пример:

```java
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RSSFeed rss;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt= new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                            ControllerThreadTood c = ControllerThreadTood.getInstance("https://lenta.ru/rss/news");
                       try {
                            rss = c.read();

                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                        Log.d("TOG", "CHANEL  " + rss.getChannelTitle());
                        Log.d("TOG", "COUNT THREAD   " + Thread.activeCount());
                       }

               }).start();
           }
       };
       timer.schedule(tt,0, 1000);
    }

    static class ControllerThreadTood {
        private static String url;
        RSSFeed rss;
        String BASE_URL;
        String RSS;
        VogellaAPI vogellaAPI;
        Retrofit retrofit;
        Call<RSSFeed> call;

        private static ControllerThreadTood cntrTh;

        public static  ControllerThreadTood getInstance(String urll){
            url = urll;
            cntrTh = new ControllerThreadTood();
            return cntrTh;
        }

        public RSSFeed read() throws Exception {
            BASE_URL = getUrLRSS(url);
            RSS= getUrLSufixRSS(url);
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            vogellaAPI = retrofit.create(VogellaAPI.class);
            call = vogellaAPI.loadRSSFeed(RSS);
            if (RSS.equals("rss/news"))
                call = vogellaAPI.loadRSSFeedNews();
            if (RSS.equals("all.php"))
                call = vogellaAPI.loadRSSFeedPHP();
            if (RSS.equals("news.rss"))
                call = vogellaAPI.loadRSSFeedNewsPointRss();
            Response<RSSFeed> response = call.execute();
            rss =response.body();
            return rss;

        }

        private  String getUrLRSS(String fullUrl){
            int posPoint = fullUrl.lastIndexOf("/");
            return  fullUrl.substring(0, posPoint+1);
        }
        private  String getUrLSufixRSS(String fullUrl){
            int posPoint = fullUrl.lastIndexOf("/");
            return  fullUrl.substring(posPoint+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Язык то какой? Укажите в метках язык.

Comment: язык JAVA. среда - андроид студио

Comment: Как вариант timer перенести в один поток)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы запускаете поток за каждый цикл таймера.
Нужно делать так:

```
mTimer = new Timer();
mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 1000);

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // ваш код
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // работа с UI
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Источник http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php

Comment: В настоящем приложении ControllerThreadTood  запускаю в сервисе для уведомлений. поэтому и Thread в таймере.

Comment: Поток в Timer потому что работа  с сетью надо в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Если в этот поток поставлю заглушку (эмулирующую загрузку)  то потоки после отработки убиваются системой. У меня ощущение что как то надо закрывать соединение для Retrofit

Comment: А вобще подобный алгоритм у меня в Servise  для создания уведомлений.

Comment: Поток один должен быть, а вы его создаете каждый раз новый